# What does heroku repo:reset not delete the source code in the Heroku repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

If I do `heroku repo:reset --app appname`, after making me enter the appname again, then it seems to do a reset.   But if I run `heroku run bash --app appname` and then do an `ls` command, all my source code still appears to be there.  According to this [heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), this command should delete all my appname source code on heroku. Why is this not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what this command does.

If you [deploy to Heroku using `git push`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploy-your-code), you push into a Git repository owned by Heroku. When that happens, Heroku builds an [application slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler):

> Slugs are compressed and pre-packaged copies of your application optimized for distribution to the [dyno manager](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-dyno-manager). When you git push to Heroku, your code is received by the slug compiler which transforms your repository into a slug. Scaling an application then downloads and expands the slug to a dyno for execution.

Your application runs from the application slug, not the raw source code.

`heroku repo:reset` resets the underslying Git repository. It does nothing to the compiled slug, nor does it scale your dynos. If you try to [clone your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app), you should find that the remote repository is empty.

You can view the url of the Git repository using `git remove -v`. If you use `heroku run bash` you can see the files that were compiled into your application slug at build time.

It's not totally clear what you want to do, but you might be looking for [`heroku apps:destroy`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-destroy), but be aware that this will permanently destroy an app.

Comment: When you run `heroku run bash` and list the files you are looking at the files that were compiled into your application slug at build time. Depending on the technology stack, that may look a lot like your source code. Or it may not.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what your second question is. `origin` is just a remote name. Often it is the remote from which you cloned your local copy. Or it may be some central repository that you choose to treat specially, e.g. something on GitHub. Usually, the remote associated with Heroku's Git repository is called `heroku` (though this can vary depending how you set everything up).

Comment: "That is what I should go to if I want to make sure that what I think I am pushing"—you're trying to verify the commit hash that got deployed? The answer to that actually depends on how you're deploying... are you using the GitHub Integration feature?